# When pressing the button, a number should be displayed and counted up at the date picker

Tags: java, javafx, datepicker, fxml

If I press the "selected" button, a number should be displayed at today's date at the Datepicker and this should be counted up the more often I press the "selected" button.

So for example:

Today we have the 27.05, so if I press the button "selected" a one there, if I press the button again should a two there if I press the button a third time should be a three there and so on.

[image]

I hope someone can help, thanks in advance.

My Code:

Main.java

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 400));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Controller.java

```
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.DateCell;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javax.security.auth.callback.Callback;
import java.net.URL;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private Button button1;

    @FXML
    private DatePicker datePicker;       
}
```

sample.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <children>
      <Button fx:id="button1" layoutX="344.0" layoutY="68.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="selected" />
      <DatePicker fx:id="datePicker" layoutX="45.0" layoutY="56.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**EDIT:**

Controller.java

```
package sample;


    import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
    import javafx.event.EventHandler;
    import javafx.fxml.FXML;
    import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
    import javafx.scene.control.Button;
    import javafx.scene.control.DateCell;
    import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;
    import javafx.scene.control.Label;

    import javax.security.auth.callback.Callback;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.time.LocalDate;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.ResourceBundle;

    public class Controller implements Initializable {

        private int clicksCounter = 0;
        private String date = String.valueOf(LocalDate.now().getDayOfMonth());

        @FXML
        private Button button2;

        @FXML
        private DatePicker datePicker;

        @Override
        public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
            button2.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                    clicksCounter++;
                }
            });

            javafx.util.Callback<DatePicker, DateCell> set = new javafx.util.Callback<DatePicker, DateCell>() {
                @Override
                public DateCell call(final DatePicker datePicker) {
                    return new DateCell() {
                        @Override public void updateItem(LocalDate item, boolean empty) {
                            super.updateItem(item, empty);
                            //if today, change text and style
                            if (item.equals(LocalDate.now())) {
                                setText(date +"/" + clicksCounter);
                                setStyle("-fx-background-color: #ffc0cb;");
                            }
                        }
                    };
                }
            };
            //datePicker.setDayCellFactory(dayCellFactory);


        }
    }
```

Comment: I do not understand where do you want the number of clicks (1,2,3...) show

Comment: Excuse me. In the picture you can see the 27 with the gray edge. There should then be the 1,2,3 so today's date. Do you understand it better?

Comment: So you want to replace the date display (27) with the number of clicks. I wonder why. Anyway first have you button do **something**. I don't see that it has any handler associated with it.

Comment: No, I do not want to replace the 27 but it is still the 27 remain the numbers should also be there.

Comment: The edit is actually a different question which requires a different post/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control and manipulate a single (or multiple) [DateCell](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/DateCell.html) using [cell factory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/DatePicker.html#dayCellFactoryProperty). Note the comments :

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.DateCell;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class FxTest extends Application {

    private int clicksCounter = 0; //count clicks
    //todays date as string
    private String date = String.valueOf(LocalDate.now().getDayOfMonth());

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker();
        //construct a cell factory
        final Callback<DatePicker, DateCell> dayCellFactory = new Callback<DatePicker, DateCell>() {
            @Override
            public DateCell call(final DatePicker datePicker) {
                return new DateCell() {
                    @Override public void updateItem(LocalDate item, boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);
                        //if today, change text and style
                        if (item.equals(LocalDate.now())) {
                            setText(date +"/" + clicksCounter);
                            setStyle("-fx-background-color: #ffc0cb;");
                        }
                    }
                };
            }
        };
        datePicker.setDayCellFactory(dayCellFactory); //assign cell factory to picker

        Button button = new Button("Selected");
        button.setOnAction(e -> clicksCounter++); //update counter

        VBox vBox = new VBox( button, datePicker);
        Scene scene = new Scene(vBox, 400, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args);}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Excuse me again, but I work with the SceneBuilder. And I work with the 3rd classes (Main, Controller and sample.fxml). How would the code look like if I left the main as with me above and would only change the controller (of course, sample.fxml)?

Comment: Try to create and set the cell factory in the controller.

Comment: I tried, unfortunately, the number and the color red is not displayed and when clicking on the button, nothing changes.

Comment: It hard without seing what you did. Please post a new question with [mcve] of the modified code. Send me a message here and I'll try to help.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've edited my post, that's what my Controller.Java looks like, had to comment out something. Where must `datePicker.setDayCellFactory (dayCellFactory);` way and what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Answer to the edited question:
There are 2 errors:

In the `fxml` you use

```
Button fx:id="button1"
```

And in the controller :

```
@FXML
private Button button2;
```

which is wrong. need to be the same name as in `fxml`  : button1. 
(Since button2 is not defined in the `fxml` using it must have thrown a `NullPointerException` which should not be ignored)

The second one is this: you changed the name of the cell factory to set
`javafx.util.Callback<DatePicker, DateCell> set`

which should also be changed here: 
`datePicker.setDayCellFactory(dayCellFactory);` 
otherwise it will not compile.

Comment: Feedback would be appreciated